# Is it possible for a class to have a member function?

Tags: objective-c

I've currently got some code as follows:

```
static void callback(several parameters)
{
   ...
}

@implementation SomeClass
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        id ct = CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault();
        CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver((__bridge CFNotificationCenterRef)(ct), NULL, callback, NULL, NULL, CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorHold);
       ....
```

Within the callback function's body I want to update some values, and I'd rather add them as properties of SomeClass rather than be global variables.
So is it possible to make the callback function a member function of SomeClass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a C API that takes a callback and you want one of your class's instance methods to be called, you have to use a C function as a trampoline. Along with the callback function, most such C APIs allow you to specify a user value that gets passed back as an argument to callback. You should pass the instance pointer as that user value. Then, your trampoline will just call an instance method on the object.

For example:

```
static void callback(void* userValue, /* other parameters... */)
{
    MyClass* myObject = (__bridge MyClass*)userValue;
    [myObject myMethod:/* other parameters passed along */];
}
```

You'll have to figure out if `CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver()` can take such a user value argument and which it is.

It doesn't much matter if `callback()` is declared inside or outside of the `@implementation`.

Comment: Better answer than mine. This and the one from @markbessey both have valuable info.

Answer (score 1):

> So is it possible to make the callback function a member function of
>   SomeClass

Not really. A method requires an object to act on. What you normally *can* do, depending on the API you're using, is to store a pointer to your SomeClass instance, and pass it as an additional parameter for the addObserver function.

Presumably one of the NULL arguments in your call to CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver is supposed to be additional context for the callback routine. You can convert a pointer to an object to a (void *) pointer when passing it to the CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver, and then convert it back to a (SomeClass *) inside the callback function.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

See my comment below. My answer should not be the accepted answer.

---

Move `callback` inside your `@implementation`, like this:

```
@implementation

- (void)callback:(SomeType)parameter1 parameter2:(SomeOtherType)parameter2 {
    // do stuff
}

...

@end
```

If you want your method to be public, you need to add it to your interface:

```
@interface

- (void)callback:(SomeType)parameter1 parameter2:(SomeOtherType)parameter2;

@end
```

[Apple's Objective-C intro](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW1) may help.

Comment: The question used the `callback` with `CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver()`. The instance method you suggest can't be used that way.

Comment: @KenThomases After re-reading the question more carefully, you're exactly right. Withdrawing my answer in favor of yours and Mark Bessey's below below.

Comment: It does does - just replace "-" with static.